# Weak Convergence in $l^p$ Erwin Kreyszig 4.8-6

Tags: functional-analysis

In Erwin Kreyszig's "Introduction to Functional Analysis" there is the following statement:[image]

It seems to me that if every entry in $x_n=(\xi_j^{(n)})$ converges to $\xi_j$ then $x_n\longrightarrow x$, which is the definition of strong convergence. If this is the case, the statement reduces to

> Weak convergent if and only if strong convergent.

Edit: Anna has pointed out that my mistake lies in the statement: "if every entry in $x_n=(\xi_j^{(n)})$ converges to $\xi_j$ then $x_n\longrightarrow x$". Can someone help explain why this is untrue?

Edit2: Finally, the intuition hits. Thank you Anna.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that weak convergence does not necessarily imply strong convergence without counterexample.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785790/prove-that-weak-convergence-does-not-necessarily-imply-strong-convergence-withou) The proof by counterexample given there for your "thought that in $l^2$ weak convergence $\nRightarrow$ strong convergence" should help you to realize that your "if every entry in $x_n=(\xi_j^{(n)})$ converges to $\xi_j$ then $x_n\longrightarrow x$" was wrong.

Comment: @AnneBauval I have seen the proof in the link before; I am trying to understand why what I said is untrue. I will edit my question.

Comment: What don't you understand in that counterexample? (a) the fact that every entry of $(e_n)$ converges to 0 or (b) the fact that $(e_n)$ does not (strongly) converge to 0?

Comment: @AnneBauval I understand that the sequence $(e_n)$ converges weakly to 0 because of Riesz representation and Bessel's inquality. Clearly it doesn't converge strongly. I believe the theorem. I guess I am just unused to thinking about sequences like this. Thank you for your help.